# vacation feature horde5, dovecot2, sieve

Tags: dovecot, horde

I am trying to activate the horde's vacation feature, but I can't make it work under SSL/TLS.
When I  "save/enable,disable" I get the following errors:

```
dovecot: managesieve-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=xxx, lip=xxx, TLS handshaking, session=<xxx>
```

```
Script not updated: exception 'Ingo_Exception' with message 'There was an error activating the script. The driver said: exception 'Ingo_Exception' with message 'Failed to establish TLS connection' in /usr/local/www/horde/ingo/lib/Transport/Timsieved.php:88
```

But when I send an email, it works

```
dovecot: managesieve-login: Login: user=<xx@xxxxx>, method=PLAIN, rip=xxxxx, lip=xxxx, mpid=xxxx, secured, session=<xxxx>
```

If it helps, thunderbirds works fine (send/receive). In addition, if I change the usetls option of the backend.local.php file to false, it works.

`dovecot.conf`:

```
# 2.2.15: /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.6 (3e924b1b6c5c+)
# OS: FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE amd64  
auth_cache_negative_ttl = 1 mins
auth_cache_size = 1 k
auth_mechanisms = digest-md5 plain
listen = *
mail_access_groups = virtual
mail_gid = virtual
mail_location = maildir:~/
mail_uid = virtual
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date ihave duplicate
passdb {
  args = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  sieve = /var/spool/virtual/%d/%n/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_dir = /var/spool/virtual/%d/%n/
}
protocols = imap lmtp sieve
service auth-worker {
  user = dovecot
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  chroot = login
  client_limit = 128
  executable = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/imap-login
  inet_listener imaps {
    address = *
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
  process_limit = 64
  process_min_avail = 2
  service_count = 10
}
service imap {
  executable = /usr/local/libexec/dovecot/imap
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
  service_count = 1
  vsz_limit = 64 M
}
service managesieve {
  process_limit = 10
}
ssl_cert = /etc/ssl/dovecot/server.crt
ssl_cipher_list = AES256+EECPH:AES256+EDH
ssl_key = /etc/ssl/dovecot/server.key
ssl_protocols = TLSv1.2
userdb {
  args = uid=virtual gid=virtual home=/var/spool/virtual/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
protocol sieve {
  log_path = /var/log/dovecot-sieve-errors.log
  mail_max_userip_connections = 10
  managesieve_implementation_string = Dovecot Pigeonhole
  managesieve_max_line_length = 65536
}
protocol imap {
  imap_client_workarounds = delay-newmail tb-extra-mailbox-sep
  imap_max_line_length = 64 k
  mail_plugins = 
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = sieve
}
```

Ingos `backends.local.php`:

```
$backends['imap']['disabled'] = true;
$backends['sieve']['disabled'] = false;
$backends['sieve']['transport'][Ingo::RULE_ALL]['params']['hostspec'] = 'xxxx';
$backends['sieve']['transport'][Ingo::RULE_ALL]['params']['logintype'] ='PLAIN';
$backends['sieve']['transport'][Ingo::RULE_ALL]['params']['usetls'] = true;
$backends['sieve']['script'][Ingo::RULE_ALL]['params']['utf8'] = true;
```

Could you help me to find out what I miss?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have to use TLS on the localhost (seriously)?